# Laravel installation tutorial says to add ~/.composer/vendor/bin to my $PATH, but it doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-14.04

I've tried a couple of methods to install laravel, including this command:

`composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`

As far as I can tell, it installs. Certainly it creates a number of directories and files, including an app directory...

When I run `laravel`, I get `command not found`. Googling, I find that I should add `~/.composer/vendor/bin` to my $PATH. The problem is that I don't have that directory. I do have `~/.composer/cache`, but the `cache` directory is the only one I have in `~/.composer`.

Any ideas on what to do? Am I missing a step? I've read a half dozen tutorials now on installing laravel. :-/

Comment: Did you run any of the commands under 'sudo'?

Comment: Also - doesn't necessarily answer your original question, but you could try the alternative install method `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Laravel is in the path ~/.config/composer/vendor/bin path. Try adding that path. But first make sure to go to that path and verify there is laravel.

Comment: This is so in my case. Laravel should update this. I mean the very starting point should not give headaches!